Add a separator line between different groups in PopUp menu
I am working with a popUp menu in android and want to add a separator between different groups of item in the menu.
I came across this already existing question but in this case, we are adding divider after each and every item. And I was able to get separating line after all the items.
However I want to add divider only after all items of a group end. Any help on that part is appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
